# Make activity with fragments scroll as if one long page

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have an activity that consists of a few fragments (all containing listviews) in a vertical linear layout. Right now, each list itself is scrollable, but what I want is for the entire activity to scroll as if everything were just one long page.

I've tried adding a scrollview around the container that I'm adding the fragments to, checking every single property that seems to be relevant, but to no avail. How can I make this work?

[image]

**XML of the activity's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout (...)
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, you can try my answer below. It may help you solve the problem and let all scroll as if one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ListViewForScrollView extends ListView {
    public ListViewForScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ListViewForScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListViewForScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
    int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * rewrite this method to let listview be suitable for scrollview.
     * after that, you can use ListViewForScrollView in ScrollView
     */
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Can I ask how the `onMeasure` method works?

Comment: In fact, this method is similar with setHeight for listview. As you can see, i set ListView's height to `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST`. But i do not advice put ListView in ScrollView. Cuz reuse of items in ListView is not work.